# Return multiple values in one cell for IF statement

Tags: excel

I want to return multiple values using an `if` statement.

For example: We have 5 columns i.e.

```
First name, Last name, DOB, Roll number, and Age
```

I want Last name and Roll number in one cell if Age = #### where there can be multiple values for Last name and Roll number for a single value of age.

Currently I'm using `textjoin` to return and join multiple values of Last name if the Roll number matches an `if` statement.

I want it to return the Last name and roll number if it satisfies the condition.

This is my formula

```
=TEXTJOIN(";",TRUE,IF(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$277=G58,Sheet1!W2:W277,""))
```

So if `Sheet1!$A$2:$A$277=G58` is `true` I want it to return `Sheet1!W2:W277` and one more value from a different column.

Thanks.

Comment: What column is the roll number?

Answer (score 2):

Just add the column for the roll number to the IF:

```
=TEXTJOIN(";",TRUE,IF(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$277=G58,Sheet1!W2:W277 & "-" & Sheet1!Y2:Y277,""))
```

Remember, this is an array formula and must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

Where column `Y` is the Roll number it will output `LastName-RollNumber` for every row that has the correct age.

Comment: That worked. Exactly what i wanted. Thank you very much.